# Natural size of user avatars twice as large as display size

Tags: html, image, css

I am new to web development and I have a question regarding the natural size of profile pictures vs their actual size.

I noticed that when I inspect element on the profile pictures on popular websites, the natural size of the avatar image is usually twice as large as the displayed size.

Some examples:

[image]

[image]

And when trying this out on my own, I noticed that images do really look better when you make sure the actual (natural) size of the image is twice as large as the displayed size.

[image]

As you can see the 64x64 picture looks a lot more crisp than the 32x32 picture. My question is if there is anything special about the two-factor. Can I make it a 128x128 picture and display it as a 32x32 to make it look even better?

Comment: Using larger than required images will increase loading time though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most images on the web are bitmap<sup>1</sup> images, which are made of hundreds of thousands of pixels. For example, a 32x32 image would have 32*32 = 1024 pixels. To display the image, the browser would have to go through every single pixel in the image. So the more pixels in the image, the longer it takes to load it.

As for why the image looks better or clearer is because the number of pixels in the original image (natural size) is the same no matter how much you zoom in or out of the image.

So when you zoom in on an image, you get the following result:
[image]

(Image from http://scientificcuriosity.blogspot.com/2006/09/how-is-digital-photo-stored.html)

The "squares" you see are individual pixels.

But if you zoom out, you get the opposite effect:

[image]

(Image from https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_we_quantify_postural_stability_when_a_human_is_standing_without_perturbation_and_with_it)

As you can see, the image is much more clear when scaled down.

But, there is a major disadvantage to large images (in terms of width and height, or number of pixels), they take **longer** to load.

The more you scale down an image, the more crisp it will look, but also smaller.

Your best option is to use a medium-sized image and display it scaled at 50% to 100%.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap

Answer (score 1):

Image clarity works on the pixel, if you using the high-resolution image for a small display it's not a good idea because High-Resolution image size is big always. your website will be slow.

you can go with this For Example - Natural Size (64x64)px and you can show in (50x50)px not the big difference of Image Pixel.

it will also show your image clear.